# Export CSV customisation

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm exporting grid and I want to customise it.
I have a boolean field say status that displays Active/Inactive as shown in below image.
[image]

How do I export this column with value Active/Inactive ?
In database I set it to 1/0 (tinyint)
**NOTE:** Also I don't want to add new hidden column with Active/Inactive value

Comment: Hello guyz,   
I just succeeded for my above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you add renderer in status field.

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Status'),
    'index' => 'status',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'options'   => array(
          1 => 'Active',
          0 => 'Inactive',
     ),
    'renderer'  => 'module/adminhtml_blockname_grid_status',
));
```

Add below code in your renderer.

```
var $status = [1 => 'Active', 0 => 'Inactive',]; 
public function renderExport(Varien_Object $row) {
    return $this->status[$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex())];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded for my above question.
Thanks to **'Zend_Db_Expr'**

Here is what you need to do.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('testimonials/usertestimonials')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->columns(array(new Zend_Db_Expr("IF (status=1, 'Active', 'Inactive') as status_text")));

    // Query dumping
    // Zend_Debug::dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
    // die;

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}

// Then  

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    ....
    $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('testimonials')->__('Status'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'width' => '100px',
            'index' => 'status',
            'type' => 'options',
            'align' => 'center',
            'renderer' => 'Aureatelabs_Testimonials_Block_Adminhtml_Testimonials_Grid_Renderer_Status',
            'options' => Mage::helper('testimonials')->getTestimonialStatusOptionArray(),
            'is_system' => 'true'
        ));

        // Add this column when export
        if ($this->_isExport) {
            $this->addColumn('status_text', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('testimonials')->__('Status Text'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'status_text',
                'align' => 'center'
            ));
        }
    ....
}
```

Let me know if you have something better than this...Thanks..